# Is My Surface Pro 3 Bricked?

Tags: boot, 16.04

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 on my Surface Pro 3(not a dual boot) and I was having troubles booting properly.  The only way that I could boot was by booting a live session via USB, pressing 'c' and the very first prompt to get to the grub2 prompt, and then running the following commands...

```
set root=(hd1,2)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

This would boot me into my OS.  I made a thread on UbuntuForums and asked about this and was told to run the following command by a user that had a sign-up date around 10 years ago...

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365116

```
sudo efibootmgr -c --disk /dev/sda --part 1 --label Ubuntu
```

After running this command I rebooted and now I can't even get a live USB session to boot.  It wont boot to anything but the Surface Pro 3's boot menu.

http://cdn.delner.com/www/images/blog/surface-linux/05_secured_boot.jpg

How can I fix this?

Comment: try this solution. https://askubuntu.com/a/920190/694267, back up you original bootx64.efi file in case you decide to go back to windows

Comment: I was finally able to boot up the live USB.  I'm not sure how I even did it.  I tried different combinations of hold down the volume buttons while booting and now I'm back in.  When I run 'sudo efibootmgr -v' I see that it deleted the Ubuntu entry that I had created.  I have two entries, 0001 is 'Windows Boot Manager' and 0002 is 'USB Drive'.  The order is 0002, 0001.