# Windows 10 dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04.2 - dual boot disappeared

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I recently installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. At first it seemed to work completely fine, restarted, came up with the GRUB and I could access Ubuntu. I think I did that twice. Then I decided to boot up Windows to check that everything there was still in order, but now the GRUB menu does not appear on start up, nor does it seem to appear at all.

To check whether the install still exists, I have tried these things:
bcdedit in Administrator mode, which does not come up with anything except the Windows boot.
The partition which I saved Ubuntu to shows as completely empty in Disk Management in Windows.
Going into BIOS settings in Boot mode to see the options and order in which they are placed. It does not appear there either.

None of them give any indication that Ubuntu is even installed. However, I want to check that I am not misunderstanding this as I am not experienced in this sort of thing and do not want to try to install something on top of what is there. Can anyone tell me if it is normal for the installation to just completely disappear or if it is likely to be able to hide it in this way?

Comment: linix file system doesn't show in windows. see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/920186/16-04-dual-boot-install-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro-efi-ubuntu-grubx64-efi-not-found/920190#920190

Comment: Yeah, this is a known problem with Windows 10. Windows updates frequently wreck your dual boot, and in some cases users have reported that their entire Linux partition got nuked. You can thank MS for that. As for checking whether or not the Ubuntu partition still exists, boot the install media and choose a live session, and see if any drives show up in the file manager other than your Windows partition.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have followed your instructions and low and behold there is another partition, and it has Liclipse installed there, which I installed before I was "blocked", so to speak. I am a bit concerned about deleting boot entries, so I guess I will read more into EFI etc. and see if I can find things there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently installed Ubuntu on a Lenevo laptop. If I reboot from Windows 10 I have to use F12 to get the grub boot menu.
When I reboot from Ubuntu I have the Windows 10 option in the grub boot menu.

So I have a workable solution to using my laptop as a dual boot even though the Ubuntu system is invisible during normal start-up. In my case it's even preferable as my children use the Windows 10 and don't need to go through the grub boot window.