# Can't load Windows 10 after updating Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

Previously, I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 installed on my laptop. Also I already configured the GRUB menu so it works perfectly fine. I was using Boot Repair once since my last problem and it ran smoothly until now.

As the title says the problem rose when I was doing a routine update. I updated my Ubuntu using the command `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Along the upgrade there is a warning that I need to disable secure boot, but I ignored that message and continued using Ubuntu as usual because the previous update didn't do anything wrong to both OSs.

After some time, I turn on my laptop and trying to boot into Windows 10 from the GRUB menu. There are lists of Windows choice, but each of them comes into a blue screen with text that says CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED.

[image]

I have tried to boot into any Windows option on the GRUB menu, changing the boot order and enabling/disabling the secure boot, but nothing resulted.

**EDIT**:
I remember vaguely that my windows is doing an update before I turned off my PC because it takes a long before shutdown and a textbox for update percentage appeared. Might try uninstalling the update first then try Rescatux.

Comment: As of right now, I am resetting my Windows 10.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot. Boot Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: If so you have a broken UEFI. Check the manufaturer's website for a possible update.

Comment: After trying to reset Windows 10, there are some errors that makes it unable to reset my Windows. @MichaelBay how could I do that without booting into my windows?

Comment: Thaty depends on the manufacturer but most allow it with just a USB stick.

Comment: @MichaelBay my bad, I actually can enable the secure boot. What should I do man?

Comment: Update-grub and hope for the best. If you still can't boot Windows then 1. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu updates, the problem was there already (and you may have issue with that drive) and 2. You will need Windows media to repair it.

Comment: You said, if I understand correctly, that the last thing you did in Windows was an update. This suggests to me that the problem is that the Windows update went badly wrong. (This does happen sometimes.) You could try using the *firmware's* boot manager to boot directly into Windows. (This is usually accessed by hitting Enter, Esc, or a function key as the computer starts up, before GRUB's menu appears; but what key to use varies from one computer to another.) If you get the same behavior when booting this way, it's almost certainly unrelated to anything Ubuntu did.

Comment: @karel I downloaded Rescatux, but 0.41 version does not have boot-isos on boot folder as the tutorial mention. I decided to put the iso anyway but the problem is I can't boot into USB even though I have selected the USB into my first boot priority. It always comes to grub. I have tried the cmd on grub but there are errors.

Comment: I think the problems exist with Windows root's file because I can go through safe mode. However, I cannot reset the pc.

Comment: It seems that my problem same as described in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920186/16-04-dual-boot-install-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro-efi-ubuntu-grubx64-efi-not-found) because one of Windows option in grub showing the exact same error text. However the answer provided still confusing me. Can anyone explain in details? @RodSmith

Comment: it seems like windows has got corrupt somehow. try running windows diagnostics

Comment: I don't see the same text in the image you posted and in [the question you referenced.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920186/16-04-dual-boot-install-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro-efi-ubuntu-grubx64-efi-not-found) The former is clearly a ***WINDOWS*** error, whereas the latter describes a problem with Shim being unable to launch GRUB. You've almost certainly got a Windows problem, although there's a small chance that GRUB is misconfigured in a way that's preventing Windows from booting, hence my suggestion to try launching Windows via the *EFI's* boot manager, thus bypassing GRUB.